# Awesome WM: tags as a m-by-n matrix? (more tags!)

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

With the vanilla configuration of Awesome you get nine tags. I would need more tags in order to support multiple 'activities' simultaneously. (Activities could for example be: "general computer usage", "coding", "graphics editing").

I think of the default nine tags as "a row". I would like to have multiple "rows" of tags, i.e. 3x9, three rows with nine tags each. It could be thought of as an m-by-n matrix of tags.

I would keep each activity and the programs needed for it in its own row.

By default, [modkey]-[left/right] moves between tags. [modkey]-[up/down] could be used to move between rows.

Wouldn't this be awesome? 
Unfortunately I am totally inexperienced when it comes to programming in lua, and the awesome API. What modifications would be needed to implement this?

Comment: Maybe this belongs on Super User or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)? Stack Exchange is primarily for Q & A about coding. So, you need to at least include some Lua here that shows what you've tried and what went wrong. But since any Lua included here will be very specific to this window manager, I think it would be better elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't be a problem. You have to add as many tags as you want (m*n) and add the following to your rc.lua:

```
awful.key({ modkey,           }, "Down",
    function () awful.tag.viewidx(n) end, --Replace the n!
    {description = "view previous", group = "tag"}),
awful.key({ modkey,           }, "Up",
    function () awful.tag.viewidx(-n) end, --Replace the n!
    {description = "view previous", group = "tag"}),
```

But unfortunately I have no idea to display the tag list as a matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and it essentially works, though I can see a few things that would be nice to improve. (1) If I create another "row" (= 2x9 ~ 18 tags) the taglist widget becomes huge since it displays 18 entries. I'm thinking that it would be suitable if the taglist only displays the current "row". (2) It would be good if the taglist and commands such as [modkey]-[number] were "row-aware" and operated within the scope of the current "row", for example if you press [modkey]-[1] or click [1] on the taglist you always switch to the first tag of the first row.

Comment: Shouldn't `n` always be `1` here? ([docs](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/tag.html#awful.tag.viewidx) say index is relative)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me (Awesomewm 4.3). Pressing `up` does the same as pressing `left`. Am I doing something wrong or was I wrong about `n`, or does this need some additional tweaks to work (like a fake second screen?)